# Pandas - Search for keyword

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to search for a keyword in a dataframe and print the keyyword if found using the following code:

```
if df[df['description'].str.contains(keyword,case=False)]:
    print(keyword)
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: @BigBen that message is incomprehensible for beginners, usually.

Comment: Also, I think this might actually be a use for `.any()`. Usually it's better for the OP to change there code, but here...

Comment: yeah sometimes this place feels like the Q&A of Python 101

Comment: @ZLi it can feel like that if you spend most of your SO time _in the [tag:python] tag_...:)

Comment: @user17242583 I mean I feel there used to be good questions which requires some thinking and more than 1 line as an answer...

Comment: I agree with that, @Z.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
if df['description'].str.contains(keyword,case=False).any():
    print(keyword)
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

`df['description'].str.contains(keyword,case=False)` returns a column, the same length as `df['description']`, containing `True` or `False` values, where each corresponds to the value of the same index in `df['description']`. If that value contained the `keyword`, the value in the returned Series is `True`, otherwise, `False`.

Calling `.any()` on a Series object will return `True` if at least one value in the Series is `True`. If all of them are `False`, `.any()` will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression

```
df[df['description'].str.contains(keyword,case=False)]
```

Doesn't return a bool, it returns a subset of the original dataframe containing the rows that match the predicate (contains keyword). So as the error message implies you need to test if this dataframe is empty or not.